# Is there an SDK for making ROS apps?

Tags: ros, ide, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an SDK or IDE for making ROS apps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9578/is-there-an-sdk-for-making-ros-apps?/) by [ngmros](https://answers.ros.org/users/355/ngmros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-27

Post score: -3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is unclear. What exactly are you looking for? Could you give us an example perhaps? ROS itself is nothing more than [C++](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp) and [Python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy) libraries and applications, so no special ROS IDE is required to develop code that uses ROS libraries.

If you'd like to use an IDE for ROS development, see the ROS [IDEs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) page for details on configuring IDEs such as Eclipse or Netbeans for doing development within ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmoya](https://answers.ros.org/users/8271/mmoya/) on 2014-04-18**:
Can't edit the answer. The correct URL for IDEs is http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs